# How to set default font size in Emacs 25?

Tags: emacs25

1. Old ~/.emacs ignored in Emacs 25:

```lisp
(custom-set-faces
 ;; custom-set-faces was added by Custom.
 ;; If you edit it by hand, you could mess it up, so be careful.
 ;; Your init file should contain only one such instance.
 ;; If there is more than one, they won't work right.
 '(default ((t (:background nil :family "Droid Sans Mono" :foundry "unknown" :slant normal :weight normal :height 164 :width normal))))
```

2. Menu > Set default font, Menu > Save Options - don't save selected font after restart.

Total, options ran out. Where can I find documentation on how to do this in Emacs 25?

Comment: Hmm, strange.. I reset font settings, and everything was corrected. But the problem arose immediately after upgrading Emacs 24 > Emacs 25. All the same, thanks :)

Comment: yep, and even more strange the fat that doing `M-x load-file .emacs` after emacs has started, set the font correctly.

Answer (score 3):

You can set the font in your init.el setting file

```
(set-default-font "Inconsolata 12")
```

You can also try the following:

```
 (set-face-attribute 'default nil
                :family "Inconsolata" :height 150 :weight 'normal)
```

Answer (score 2):

These seems to be an issue with gconf overriding emacs customizations.
As answered [here](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/27191/cant-adjust-font-size-anymore-in-emacs-25).

Simply put these line in your `.emacs`

`(define-key special-event-map [config-changed-event] #'ignore)`